# Android - How to clear textView?

Tags: android, textview

I have created an android app in java using eclipse which creates a Sqlite database and lets the user add data to it. Users can also search for existing data.
I used android cursor objects.
How do I clear the text box after a query is completed ?
For example, I type "value" to retrieve all records associated with that value. Now I want to perform another search. When I click on the text box, I would like the text box to be cleared for my next search.

This is part of my code for inserting and retrieving data :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " name TEXT," + " number TEXT);");

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " (name, number)" + " VALUES ( \"" + newname + "\", \"" + newnumber + "\");", null);
cur.moveToFirst();
while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) 
{
    result.append("\n" + "Id: " + cur.getString(0) + " | " + "Name: " + cur.getString(1) + " | " + "Phone Number: " + cur.getString(2) + "\n");

    cur.moveToNext();
}
cur.close(); 

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {}  );

c.moveToFirst();

while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
    result.append("\n" + "Id: " + c.getString(0) + " | " + "Name: " + c.getString(1) + " | " + "Phone Number: " + c.getString(2) + "\n");

    c.moveToNext();
}
c.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Watch subsituting user inputs into raw queries like this since you are exposing yourself to [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) exploits.

Answer (score 19):

First you probably don't want to clear your database to just clear a textView. So the relevant code would be inside your activity.

So if you are using a textView you would do something like this in code

// Global variable

```
    TextView yourTexView;
```

// In your activities on Create

```
    yourTexView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTexView );
    yourTexView .setOnClickListener(yourClickListener)
```

// Somewhere In the activities class

```
/**
 * Tour Click Handler - This will clear the textview whenever someone clicks it. 
 */
private OnClickListener yourClickListener= new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourTexView.setText("");
    }
};
```

// In your xml file - change as you need

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourTexView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
```

Hopefully this helps,
Cheers

Comment: Great! Please click on the accept answer check mark to let others know it's solved. I'm glad that it works. =)

Answer (score 9):

Either `setText("")` or `setText(null)` — either one of those would work. I use `setText(null)` for readability reasons.

Comment: If you are worried about readability, you can also add `<string name="empty" />` to `strings.xml` and use `textView.setText(R.string.empty)` :)

Comment: @AntonioViniciusMenezesMedei That's just worse; and, unnecessary